# How to use stored procedure in ibatis?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, ibatis

How to use stored procedure in ibatis?

Comment: Please Refer http://loianegroner.com/2011/03/ibatis-mybatis-working-with-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<procedure id="getUserEmail"
  parameterClass="java.lang.String" resultClass="java.lang.String">
    {call SP_getUserEmail(#username#)}
</procedure>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this in mybatis 3:

```
<update id="myProcCall" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {    
        call MY_PROC(#{param1, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, 
         mode=IN},#{param2, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, 
         mode=IN)
     }
</update>
```